# "Find in page" in Chrome Custom Tabs menu

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#configure-a%20custom%20menu), the Custom Tabs menu includes "Find in page" and "Open in Chrome" menu items by default. In my implementation, created following the implementation guide, only "Open in Chrome" appears. How can I include the "Find in page" menu item and functionality in Custom Tabs? I know I can add a menu item with CustomTabsIntent.Builder.addMenuItem and name it "Find in page", but do I have to program the search functionality as well?

Answer (score 1):

"Find in Page" menu item comes in the default menu items. You don't need to handle this intent, it is handled by the `ChromeActivity` specifically by something called Contextual Search inside chrome.

Default [CustomTab menu resource file](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/res/menu/custom_tabs_menu.xml?type=cs&q=custom_tabs_menu&sq=package:chromium&l=1) seems doesnt include Find in page. Main `ChromeActivity` [menu resource file](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/res/menu/main_menu.xml?dr=C&q=main_menu&sq=package:chromium&l=1) includes it, maybe you need to create similar menu resource for your project. My guess is, action on these menu items will be handled by id.

Comment: I create my Custom Tab using `CustomTabsIntent` created with `CustomTabsIntent.Builder`. Even if I created my own XML menu resource with the find_in_page id, how would I pass it to the builder?